# Robocopy: copying files without their directory structure

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, file-transfer, robocopy

I have a network fileshare called `\\SMWEB\MSDS`
which contains hundreds of sub-directories named `MSDSnnnn`
(i.e., `MSDS` plus a number). 
Inside each sub-directory MAY be numerous files —
some `.html`, `.jpg` and various `.pdf` files. 
There may also be a sub-directory called `_vti_cnf`,
which contains old FrontPage extensions associated with meta-data. 
But there *should* always be at least one file within these sub-directories
with the name format `MSDS#.PDF`. 
(The number may be varying lengths;
e.g., `MSDS99.PDF` or `MSDS1099.PDF`, etc.)

There may also be old, outdated versions of these files which the owner appended an `X#_` in front of the file (see the red box in the image — there are two archival versions of the `MSDS0001.PDF` file in this example).

This is what the tree structure looks like:
        [image: tree structure, as described]

Here's what I need to accomplish: I need to copy all of the current,
top-level PDF files somewhere
(a single directory called `SDS` on my `H:\` drive). 
I do NOT want to replicate the sub-folders,
and I only want the files with the `MSDS*.PDF` pattern. 
(These files are highlighted in yellow in the above image.) 
So I want to exclude:

- files in sub-directories under `MSDSnnnn` directories
  (e.g., in `_vti_cnf` sub-directories),
- files whose names don't begin with `MSDS`
  (e.g., the `X#_` files), and
- files whose names don't end with `.PDF` (e.g., HTML and JPEG files).

I tired the following command in Robocopy:

```
robocopy \\smweb\msds\ H:\SDS msds*.pdf /S /R:3 /W:3 /NDL /XJD /XD _vti_cnf
```

The problem is that Robocopy replicated the folder structure
on my `H:` drive.

How can I accomplish my goal?

Comment: (1) Your image doesn’t match your text — the image shows an archived version of ***``MSDS0002.PDF``*** under the ``MSDS0001`` directory. (2) What should be done with file(s) in the `_vti_cnf` directories?

Comment: @Scott -- you are correct -- the archived version labeled X2_MSDS0002.PDF should have read X2_MSDS0001.PDF. The files in the _vti_cnf folders can be ignored because they are old Frontpage Extensions associated with meta-data. The files have the same name as the parent folder, but the data inside is different and should not be copied for my purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I took a two step approach.

First I ran the Robocopy command which copied all of the files and the tree structure to a temp directory called SDS1, but it excluded the "_vti_cnf" sub-folders with the extraneous meta-data:

```
robocopy \\smweb\msds\ \\smf4\HOME\gpence-home\SDS1 msds*.pdf /S /R:3 /W:3 /NDL /XJD /XD _vti_cnf
```

Then I ran a PowerShell script which removed the sub-folders in the tree by copying the files to another directory called SDS2. (The -WhatIf parameter shows you the results without actually executing the command. Simply remove that parameter when you are ready to execute the command "for real".)

```
get-ChildItem -Path "\\smf4\HOME\gpence-home\SDS1\msds*.pdf" -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination "\\smf4\HOME\gpence-home\SDS2" -WhatIf
```

That worked well for me.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using a different file copy tool? Robocopy does not support this out of the box. Here is a link that discusses that exact topic:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690245/robocopy-copy-folders-content-to-a-single-folder

You can also try something simple like this

`for /r \\SMWEB\MSDS %f in (MSDS*.pdf) do @copy "%f" H:\MSDS`